# better way to get file1 and file2 union content via linux file command?

Tags: linux, filemerge

There is a `file1` and another file `file2`, then my solution to get the union file of `file1` and `file2` is:

1. step: get the intersection set file

   ```
   comm -1 -2 file1 file2 >>intersectionFile
   ```
2. step: get the complement set file of `file1`

   ```
   comm -1 -3 file1 file2 >> file1ComplementFile
   ```
3. step: get the complement set file of `file2`

   ```
   comm -2 -3 file1 file2 >> file2ComplementFile
   ```
4. step: get the union set file equals the intersection set file PLUS `file1`'s complement set file PLUS `file2`'s complement set file

   ```
   cat intersectionFile file1ComplementFile file2ComplementFile >> unionFile
   ```

MY QUESTION IS is there a better OR easier way to get the union file of `file1` and `file2`?

Comment: file 1 file 2 are csv files ?

Comment: nope,just a data file contain flag and data,generated by log center.

Answer (score 1):

Your manipulations are identical to just `comm file1 file2 >unionFile`. Can you try just that?

Comment: thx!really works!the common part was outputed in third column,but looks not good.my intent is file1+file2-intersectionFile,not content listed in three column.